# How to select an item from a List in flutter

Tags: dart, material-design, flutter

I have list from a model like this

```
amount:"12000"
dateTime:"19/07/2018"
detail:"Soto"
hashCode:853818549
id:1
name:"Theodorus"
```

I want to just select amount and add it to another list of string, but I'm always getting this error `A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<String>'.`  , I thinks its because im not doing it right, here is my code below

```
void setupList() async {
    DebtDatabase db = DebtDatabase();
    listCache = await db.getMyDebt();
    setState(() {
      filtered = listCache;
    });
     List<String> amount = new List<String>();
    listCache.map((value)  {
      amount = value.amount;   } );
    //print(amount);
  }
```

can anyone help me, so I can get list of ammount from this model list and then sum all the ammount?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `map` function returns an iterable and you can then transform it into a list.
You should try something like this:

```
void setupList() async {
  DebtDatabase db = DebtDatabase();
  listCache = await db.getMyDebt();
  setState(() {
    filtered = listCache;
  });
  List<String> amount = listCache.map((value) => value.amount).toList();
  //print(amount);
}
```

Comment: hi how about sum list of number can you answer that too or i should make new asnwer thanks for your answer anyway , i will mark this as an asnwer